# Accessing members of inherited class from parent

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have an abstract class that has several optional methods.  Behavior changes based on whether or not any/all of these methods exist on classes that inherit from it.  In Javascript this is fairly easy:

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        if (this.doSomething) this.doSomething();
        else console.log("nothing to do!");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    doSomething() {
        console.log("doing my thing");
    }
}

const myThing = new ChildClass(); // console prints out "doing my thing"
```

The same code in TypeScript won't work:

```
interface ParentClass {
    doSomething?(): void;
}

abstract class ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        if (this.doSomething) this.doSomething();
        else console.log("nothing to do!");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    doSomething = () => {
        console.log("doing my thing");
    }
}

const myThing = new ChildClass(); // console prints out "nothing to do!"
```

Under-the-hood TypeScript doesn't use native classes - In `ParentClass`, `this` can only access members explicitly defined in `ParentClass` and `self` always refers to the `window` object.

**Is it possible to access members of a child class from the class that it inherits from?**

Alternatively is there a way to bypass TypeScript's alternative class structure?  I'm aware that it's possible to do this with a function instead of a class, but in my actual use-case `ParentClass` inherits from `React.Component` and I'm not entirely sure how to shoe-horn that inheritance in without breaking everything.

**EDIT:** This post has been edited to reflect the actual problem.  Previously the function `doSomething` was a method, not a self-binding property.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Deep inheritance graphs are discouraged in React.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yeah, it's something I've sort of backed myself into unfortunately

Comment: Are you [sure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20ParentClass%20%7B%0A%20doSomething%3F%28%29%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0Aabstract%20class%20ParentClass%20%7B%0A%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20%28this.doSomething%29%20this.doSomething%28%29%3B%0A%20%20else%20console.log%28%22nothing%20to%20do%21%22%29%3B%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20ChildClass%20extends%20ParentClass%20%7B%0A%20doSomething%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28%22doing%20my%20thing%22%29%3B%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20myThing%20%3D%20new%20ChildClass%28%29%3B) it doesn't work?

Comment: TypeScript does use native classes under the hood if you specify a new enough `--target` in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  And the ES5 target prints out `"doing my thing"` when I test it myself on your code.  So, uh, I can't reproduce your issue.  You might need to add more info or do more work to get a [mcve].

Comment: @jcalz I swear I tested my above code on exactly that editor and it didn't work.  Looks like I've got a little more research to do.

Comment: @jcalz I tried setting target to ES6, ES2018 - neither seemed to work.  HOWEVER my above code seems to be working in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) which I swear it absolutely did not before.  I may have to circle back round on this one.

Comment: Well, I can't account for why I remember this code not working when I tried it yesterday, but I found my problem - it was very specific and not at all related to the question above.  I guess I've got to chalk this one up to poor attention on my part.  Sorry to take up your times.

Comment: No problem, glad you found your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doSomething` can't be a property, it must be a method.

```
interface ParentClass {
    doSomething?(): void;
}

abstract class ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        if (this.doSomething) this.doSomething();
        else console.log("nothing to do!");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    doSomething() {
        console.log("doing my thing");
    }
}

const myThing = new ChildClass();
```